# :before / :after tag in inline css (workaround?)

Tags: css, email, inline

So I'm trying to put animated css into an email signature. I got it to work in iOS / Mac email-clients, but Gmail and Outlook seem to block part of the code. Does anyone maybe know of a workaround?

The code that I use now in my email:

```
    <!doctype HTML>
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
 <head style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <style rel="stylesheet" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" type="text/css">
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.container {
background: #64B1EE;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
}


.airplane {
position: absolute; 
left: 40%;
top: 10%;
z-index: 3;
-webkit-animation: plainfly 10s linear infinite;
-o-animation: plainfly 10s linear infinite;
animation: plainfly 10s linear infinite;
}
.airplane div {
background: #F9FBFC;
border-radius: 100%;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
div.head  {
top: 21px;
left: 83px;
width: 60px;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 100%;
}
div.body  {
top: 20px;
left: 0;
width: 130px;
height: 26px;
border-radius: 40% 30% 20% 50%;
z-index: 1
}
div.lwing {
top: 7px;
left: 60px;
height: 21px;
width: 30px;  
border-radius: 5px; 
z-index: 0 ;
-webkit-transform: skew(51deg, 0deg);
-ms-transform: skew(51deg, 0deg);
-o-transform: skew(51deg, 0deg);
transform: skew(51deg, 0deg);
}
div.rwing {
top: 34px;
left: 57px;
height: 27px; 
width: 35px;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1; 
box-shadow: 0px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
-webkit-transform: skew(-49deg, 0deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-49deg, 0deg);
-o-transform: skew(-49deg, 0deg);
transform: skew(-49deg, 0deg);
}
div.tale  {
top: 15px;
left: 10px;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-transform: skew(35deg, -9deg);
-ms-transform: skew(35deg, -9deg);
-o-transform: skew(35deg, -9deg);
transform: skew(35deg, -9deg);
background: linear-gradient(0deg,#FFF, #BBDEFF);
}
div.window,
div.window:before,
div.window:after {
content: "";
top: 6px;
left: 48px;
width: 4px; 
height: 4px; 
border-radius: 30%;
background: #9AD0F5;
border: 1px solid #5093D1;
position: absolute;
}
div.window:before {
left: -12px;
top: -1px;
}
div.window:after {
left: 10px;
top: -1px;
}
div.window:nth-child(1){
left:81px
}
div.window:nth-child(2){
left:115px
}
div.window:nth-child(2):after {
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
width: 6px;
}


@-webkit-keyframes plainfly { 
0% {
  left: -10%; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(.4);
  -o-transform: scale(.4);
  transform: scale(.4);
} 
50% {
  left: 110%; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
} 
51% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
100% {
  left: -10%; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4) rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.4) rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: scale(1.4) rotateY(180deg);
  transform: scale(1.4) rotateY(180deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud   { 
0% { left: 15%; }
50% { left: 63%; } 
100% { left: 15%; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_a { 
0% { left: 62%; }
50% { left: 90%; } 
100% { left: 62%; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_b { 
0% { left: 50%; }
50% { left: 23%; } 
100% { left: 50%; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_c { 
0% { left: 37%; }
50% { left: 47%; } 
100% { left: 37%; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_d { 
0% { left: 25%; }
50% { left: 65%; } 
100% { left: 25%; }
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <div class="container" style="background: #64B1EE; height: 100%; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%;"><airplane class="airplane" style="animation: plainfly 10s linear infinite; left: 40%; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 10%; z-index: 3;"><div class="head" style="background: #F9FBFC; border-radius: 100%; height: 25px; left: 83px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 21px; width: 60px; z-index: 1;">
    </div>
    <div class="body" style="background: #F9FBFC; border-radius: 40% 30% 20% 50%; height: 26px; left: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 20px; width: 130px; z-index: 1;">
     <div class="window" style="background: #9AD0F5; border: 1px solid #5093D1; border-radius: 30%; content: ""; height: 4px; left: 48px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 6px; width: 4px; z-index: 1;">
     </div>
     <div class="window" style="background: #9AD0F5; border: 1px solid #5093D1; border-radius: 30%; content: ""; height: 4px; left: 48px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 6px; width: 4px; z-index: 1;">
     </div>
     <div class="window" style="background: #9AD0F5; border: 1px solid #5093D1; border-radius: 30%; content: ""; height: 4px; left: 48px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 6px; width: 4px; z-index: 1;">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lwing" style="background: #F9FBFC; border-radius: 5px; height: 21px; left: 60px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 7px; transform: skew(51deg, 0deg); width: 30px; z-index: 0;">
    </div>
    <div class="rwing" style="background: #F9FBFC; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); height: 27px; left: 57px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 34px; transform: skew(-49deg, 0deg); width: 35px; z-index: 1;">
    </div>
    <div class="tale" style="background: linear-gradient(0deg,#FFF, #BBDEFF); border-radius: 2px; height: 16px; left: 10px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 15px; transform: skew(35deg, -9deg); width: 16px; z-index: 1;">
    </div></airplane></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle to make it easier: https://jsfiddle.net/rvrvbtL9/

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only work around is you can use animated `.gif` image

Comment: i thought about that, but old versions of outlook put .gif images as an attachement....

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is created by the email clients removing everything within a `<style>` tag. Email clients all process HTML emails different and most of the time you will have to use limited inline styles with a table based layout for best compatiblity.

[This](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) is a great resource.

Comment: thanks for the link - so little is supported! Do you, or does anyone else, have a workaround so I get the same output in a different way?

Comment: @petervries, unfortunately there is no "easy" work around. you will have to apply inline-styles and insure it displays properly in all clients. Typically people will actually (As a developer I hate to say...) use a service for HTML email generation and testing. [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) is a 3rd party service offering this testing. Please note this is not a recommendation. It is merely showing the services exist.

Comment: thank you for the info. Am I right in saying that moving an object in CSS is impossible for emails?

Comment: @Arman Ozak hit the animation issue on the head, it will have to be an animated GIF which may not load in Gmail by default (They block images by default).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Gmail will allow styles but they must NOT be in the body, the previous poster is correct that they require inline css and nothing global. They also strip the HEAD. They strip out class, id and styles from the body. Also no positioning may NOT be used even if its inline. Images need to be on a publicly accessible server, Outlook for instance will not handle base64 encoded images.

Your solution: Remove your classes, all positioning code, HEAD, and convert everything inline. You can use this tool to help you do that: [MailChimp Inline converter](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) Instead of positioning, tables are your friend.

[Litmus](https://litmus.com) is a fantastic tool to view your html in several clients.

Answer (score 0):

MattSizzle has already written everything I was planning to say about CSS in emails and email clients (along with the same reference link).

In your case, using an **animated GIF** instead of a CSS animation might be a good practice. It has better browser compatibility as seen [here](https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-animated-gifs-in-email). Nevertheless, animated GIF in email has its own drawbacks, such as "some Outlook versions not showing the animation but the first frame only". Take a look at the article. It may help.